# How can I Get the Related Product Slider

Tags: magento-1.9, product, related-products, slider

How can I Get the **Related Product Slider** on **Product Detail Page**? I am Using Magento 1.9.2.3 Version.

Comment: have u tried so far

Comment: yes. i tried "https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi6zaOJsPLNAhVGOI8KHZN7BA0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.magentocommerce.com%2Fmagento-connect%2Frelated-product-slider-1.html&usg=AFQjCNF_B2CwWLXdLY5uQw7xZxBFQtFk0g&bvm=bv.126993452,d.c2I" above link. but i think there is version problem. can you help me for this.

Comment: please try youself install  html slider like flexslider ,bx slider,then we  will help u